# How to append dynamic values to URL?

Tags: angular

I've a `Util.ts` which will have all the API endpoints.

In my component will import the `Api` class and make use of the API's.

Now, One of the API endpoint is having dynamic values, that I need to append to the URL.

**Utils.ts**

```
export class Api {
    public static PROGRESS_ISSUE = 'https://xxx/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%20%3D%2025764%20AND%20status%20%3D%20%22In%20Progress%22&fields=id,key,status,project&maxResults=100'
}
```

In the above, I wanted to make the `project` & `status` as dynamic values which I'll be passing in the service.

**Service.ts**

```
import { Api } from './api/utils'; 

  getJiraOpenIssues(id: number, status:string) {
    return this.http.get<any>( Api.PROGRESS_ISSUE )
    .subscribe(count => console.log(count.total));
  }
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters, https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place some placeholder string on the PROGRESS_ISSUE, and then use `replace` to replace it with the actual value:

```
export class Api {
  public static PROGRESS_ISSUE = "https://xxx/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=PROJECTPLACEHOLDER&status=STATUSPLACEHOLDER&fields=id,key,status,project&maxResults=100"
}
```

Then, in your `getJiraOpenIssues` method, use replace:

```
import { Api } from './api/utils';

getJiraOpenIssues(id: number, status: string) {
  const apiUrl = Api.PROGRESS_ISSUE
    .replace('PROJECTPLACEHOLDER', 'YOUR PROJECT ID HERE')
    .replace('STATUSPLACEHOLDER', 'YOUR PROJECT STATUS HERE');
  return this.http.get<any>(apiUrl)
    .subscribe(count => console.log(count.total));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append values like we concat string with + operator.

```
   getJiraOpenIssues(id: number, status:string) {
        return this.http.get(Api.PROGRESS_ISSUE + '' + id + '/'+status)
            .map((response) => response.json());
    }
```